# "This Friday" in bash script

Tags: bash, date

Is there a way to calculate a time stamp for the next coming up of a week day?

So for instance, with friday, i'd like to be able to run some code that calculates that from today Wednesday 19/05/10, the next friday will be 21/05/10 and get a time stamp from it.

I know the date command can parse a given string date according to a format, but I can't figure out how to calculate "next friday from today"

Any idea?

EDIT: I'm on a mac

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With GNU date:

```
date -d 'this Friday' '+%d/%m/%y'
```

See [Relative items in date strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings), part of the GNU date documentatoin.  There are also [examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html).

Comment: If that command is run on Sat/Sun, will it return this week date or next week date?

Comment: @DJ, I think it always returns today or a future day, within 7 days from the start of today.  For me, it's currently Wed. the 19th, so 'this Tuesday' gives Tue. the 25th.  An interesting point is that 'this Wednesday' gives the 19th, while 'next Wednesday' is the 26th.

Comment: Next week date. According to the `date` docs, "this" is equivalent to not specifying anything, so it looks for the next Friday which occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What's the equivalent of date -d on Mac ? (Sorry I should have mentioned that)

Comment: I've worked it out on the mac.. 
date -v+Friday  
or 
date -v+Friday "+%s" for the timestamp

Comment: More relative dates: Today (Wednesday) using "Friday" and "next Friday" both give "May 21". You can do "Friday week" to get "May 28" or "Friday 2 weeks" to get "June 4".

Answer (score 0):

Since no format was specified, it's much simpler:

```
date -d Fri
```

'this' is assumed par default, Friday can be abbreviated. Since it is just one word - or the significant rest of it, (ask Th) it doesnt need Quotes like

```
 date -d "last Fri"
```

would.

Comment: Yes, but it was linked on the right side, when working at an actual question (about the Friday before a random date), so I thought: visit this link - most people underestimate the power of `date`.

Comment: Sure, i'll give you one point for your undiminishable appreciation of the power of date